# python cmd completedefault() method not called

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following Python 2.7 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cmd

class T(cmd.Cmd):
    def completedefault(self, *a):
        print 'completedefault called'
        return []

t=T()
t.cmdloop()
```

When I expect:

I type a character into the shell, then hit tab, I expect to see "completedfault called" printed.

What actually happens:

I type a character into the shell, then hit tab, and nothing happens.

Tested with Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`completedefault` is called to complete a input line *after* you entered a command for which no `complete_<commandname>`-method is available.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cmd

class T(cmd.Cmd):
    def completedefault(self, *a):
        print 'completedefault called'
        return []

    def test(self, *args):
        print "test args: ", args

t=T()
t.cmdloop()
```

now enter `test` [space] and press tab, `completedefault` should be executed now.

If you want to control completion for command names, you can use `completenames` to do so, not `completedefault`.