# Cmd module : having completion on the first word

Tags: python, autocomplete, cmd, code-completion

I use `completedefault` ([see the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.completedefault)) for completion with `Cmd` module. But it seems to be called only after the first word.

```
def completedefault(self,text,line,begidx,endidx):                                          
     print('completedefault is called')                                                      
     return ['foo','bar']
```

Output :

```
(Cmd) f<Tab><Tab>
(Cmd) foo f<Tab><Tab>
completedefault is called
foo bar
```

How to change this behavior to have it called even on the first word ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually simple : `Cmd.completenames`. More info [here](http://fossies.org/dox/Python-2.7.6/classcmd_1_1Cmd.html#a2d31e78d2f6c1abc592b9b2639059058). A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723012/python-cmd-completedefault-method-not-called).